# pandas: how to remove duplicates from a deeply nested list of lists

Tags: pandas, list, nested, duplicates, flatten

I have a panda dataframe like the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'text':['the weather is nice though', 'How are you today','the beautiful girl and the nice boy']})
df['sentence_number'] = df.index + 1
df['token'] = df['text'].str.split().tolist()
df= df.explode('token').reset_index(drop=True)
```

I have to have a column for tokens as I need it for another project. I have applied the following to my dataframe.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

dep_children_sm = []

def dep_children_tagger(txt):
    children = [[[child for child in n.children] for n in doc] for doc in nlp.pipe(txt)]
    dep_children_sm.append(children)


dep_children_tagger(df.text)
```

since one has to apply the n.children method on the sentence level, I have to use the text column and not the token column, so the output has a list of repetitions. I would now like to remove this repetitions from my list 'dep_children_sm', and i have done the following,

```
children_flattened =[item for sublist in dep_children_sm for item in sublist]
list(k for k,_ in itertools.groupby(children_flattened))
```

but nothing happens, and I still have the repeated lists. I have also tried to add drop_duplicates() to the text column when calling the function, but the problem is that I have duplicate sentences in my original dataframe and unfortunately cannot do that.

```
desired output = [[[], [the], [weather, nice, though], [], []], [[], [How, you, today], [], []], [[], [], [the, beautiful, and, boy], [], [], [], [the, nice]]]
```

Comment: It is not really clear what you are trying to do. Can you provide the expected output dataframe? Also, your code is not reproducible as `nlp` is not defined.

Comment: sorry i added the output and the nlp info

Comment: @mozway, i just realized what the issue is, though i do not know how to handle it. the problem is that the children_flattened is a list of list of lists of nlp.tokens and so it is why the itertools method does not work. i guess if there is a way to turn the lists in to string, it might work though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I figured out how to solve this issue. the problem was that the nlp.text outputs a list of list of lists on spacy tokens, and since at no point there is any string in this nested list, the itertools does not work.
since I cannot remove the duplicates from the text column in my analysis, I have done the following instead.

```
d =[' '.join([str(c) for c in lst]) for lst in children_flattened]
list(set(d))
```

this outputs a list of strings excluding duplicates

```
# ['[] [How, you, today] [] []',
# '[] [the] [weather, nice, though] [] []',
# '[] [] [the, beautiful, and, boy] [] [] [] [the, nice]']
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to apply your function on the unique texts. Thus you can first use the [pandas.Series.unique](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) method on df.text

```
>>> df['text'].unique()
array(['the weather is nice though', 'How are you today',
       'the beautiful girl and the nice boy'], dtype=object)
```

Then I would simplify your function to directly output the result. There is no need for a global list. Also, your function was adding an extra level of list, which seems unwanted.

```
def dep_children_tagger(txt):
    return [[[child for child in n.children] for n in doc] for doc in nlp.pipe(txt)]
```

Finally, apply your function on the unique texts:

```
dep_children_sm = dep_children_tagger(df['text'].unique())
```

This gives:

```
>>> dep_children_sm
[[[], [the], [weather, nice, though], [], []],
 [[], [How, you, today], [], []],
 [[], [], [the, beautiful, and, boy], [], [], [], [the, nice]]]
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. unfortunately i cannot do that. I have also mentioned it in my question that i have some repeated sentences in my original df and unfortunately I cannot remove the duplicates or get the unique sentences